# Returning the words from a string that occur a number of times or more in python 3?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function, `f(x, n)`, from scratch, that returns the words that occur an `n` number of times or more in a sorted list.

For example:

```
f("the apple the banana the apple", 2)
>>> ['apple', 'the']
```

since `the` and `apple` are the only words that occur two or more times

another example:

```
f("the kid jumped off the roof", 1)
>>> ['jumped', 'kid', 'off', 'roof', the']
```

What I've tried so far with no luck:

```
def f(x, n):
   words = list(x.split())
   a= ""
   for word in words:
     if len(word) >= n:
       a += word
         return(list(word))
```

Comment: Can you use imported module functions or data objects for this? BTW, you haven't sorted your word list.

Comment: I'd prefer a code from scratch as I'm still learning the basics of pythons. And thanks for that, I'll try fixing that up.

Comment: Python is _all about_ importing the right modules. Knowing the library is 95% of the work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would iterate over the  items  present inside the  list generated after splitting and add the each item to the dictionary and it's count as `1` if the item is not exists already in that dictiornary. If the item is already exists, it would increase it's corresponding value by `1`. word acts like a key and the count acts like a value.

```
def f(x, n):
    words = x.split()
    d = {}
    for word in words:
        if word in d:
            d[word] += 1
        else:
            d[word] = 1     
    print [i for i,j in d.items() if d[i] >= n]        

f("the apple the banana the apple", 2)
```

Output:

```
['the', 'apple']
```

Comment: Awesome! thank you! Just one more thing, how would I sort  it in this case? Do i use .sorted() or .sort()?

Comment: sort will do an in-place sort where sorted will return a list after sorting. like `print sorted([i for i,j in d.items() if d[i] >= n])`

Comment: @AvinashRaj i love one-liners, but for a python beginner i appreciate your code being much more explanatory than the other samples. I did not test your function in my answer, because you posted later but you might consider removing punctuation and converting to lowercase as i explained in my answer

Answer (score 1):

The problem in the function you provide is that you're actually checking the [length](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) of each word (by doing `if len(word)...`) instead of checking is frequency in the string.

You could simply use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and a [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) like that:

```
from collections import Counter

def f(string, n):
    count = Counter(string.split()).items()
    return [i for (i, j) in count if j >= n]

print(f("the apple the banana the apple", 2))
```

Output:

```
['apple', 'the']
```

Answer (score 1):

**This is a working solution** 

Since you mentioned 'from scratch', I will write this code without importing any modules. 

**Logic:**

1.  Iterate through the list of words (only once) **{O(n) complexity}** and keep count of the number of occurrences using a dictionary. A dictionary is ideal because you can't have duplicates 

2. Iterate through the dictionary once **{O(n) complexity}** and check to see if the value is greater than N -> If so, append it to the list that will be returned (if not already in the list).

```
  def N_duplicates(string, freq): #Get's input string and Frequency
    word_count={} #Dictionary is used to store word frequencies. 
    ret_lst=[] #returning list
    lst=string.split();

    for word in lst:
        if (word not in word_count):
            word_count[word]=1
        else:
            word_count[word]=word_count[word]+1;

    for item in word_count.keys():
        if (word_count[item]>=freq):
            if (item not in ret_lst):
                ret_lst.append(item)

    return ret_lst;


print(N_duplicates("the kid jumped off the roof",1))
```

Answer (score 0):

[Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is your friend on this one. Try something like this:

```
from collections import Counter

def f(x, n):
   words = x.split()
   c = Counter(words)
   return [word for word, v in c.items() if v >= n]
```

And then:

```
>>> print(f("the kid jumped off the roof", 1))
['the', 'kid', 'off', 'roof', 'jumped']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string's [count](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.count) and [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-set) built-in functions to achieve this:

```
>>> def f(x, n):
...     return sorted(set(s for s in x.split() if x.count(s) >= n))
... 
>>> s1 = "the apple the banana the apple"
>>> s2 = "the kid jumped off the roof"
>>> f(s1, 2)
['apple', 'the']
>>> f(s2, 1)
['jumped', 'kid', 'off', 'roof', 'the']
```

Comment: I'm trying to make a function that would work for any string, similar to the examples I had.

Answer (score 0):

I do like the Answers supplied here, but i was tempted to test the result difference between the `Counter()` and the `list()` variant, so i implemented both functions so they return a sorted array with the word and the number of counts combined so i can compare results better:

```
from collections import Counter
# this is the Counter version returned sorted
def f(x,n): return sorted(["%s:%s" % (w,c) for w,c in Counter(x.split()).most_common() if c >= n])
# this is the list version returned sorted
def g(x, n): return sorted(list(set("%s:%s" % (s, x.count(s)) for s in x.split() if x.count(s) >= n)))
```

Now i fed both function with 500 Words of [Lorem Ipsum](http://www.loremipsum.de) text. And i was astonished, that there actually where differences.

A bug, that both versions have in common, is that they don't take into considerations punctuation. So if i have `Apple` in the text, it is not the same word as `Apple,` or `Apple.` or `Apple!`, and so on. Where you could easily replace/remove all punctuation before counting words.

Also `Apple` is not the same as `apple` which could be as intended, but if not you would also have to `.lower()` the string.

But the biggest difference is the counting itself. Here actually the `list()` version fails, because it counts words, if they appear within another word it seams. So function `f()` counted `at` 8 times, which was correct, but function `g()` showed 38 counts - so obviously `x.count(s)` returns not only words, but also sub matches. too bad, that makes the `list()` version fail.

Trying this with an awkward sentence gave following result:

```
>>> print f("This test so nice, is like ice! Test... likely;",1)
['Test...:1', 'This:1', 'ice!:1', 'is:1', 'like:1', 'likely;:1', 'nice,:1', 'so:1', 'test:1']

>>> print g("This test so nice, is like ice! Test... likely;",1)
['Test...:1', 'This:1', 'ice!:1', 'is:2', 'like:2', 'likely;:1', 'nice,:1', 'so:1', 'test:1']
```

Here you can see the behavior, and that the `list()` version actually counts *is* and *like* twice, because they are contained in *This* and *likely*.

So the winner is:

```
from collections import Counter
# this is the Counter version but result returned sorted
def f(x,n): return sorted([w for w,c in Counter(x.split()).most_common() if c >= n])
```

Now this still does not take into consideration upper/lower case and punctuation. If you want a result, as i would expect it, you could add the `string` module to give you the expected result:

```
from collections import Counter
import string
# return correct result lowercase without punctuation and sorted
def f(x,n): return sorted([w for w,c in Counter(x.translate(None, string.punctuation).lower().split()).most_common() if c >= n])
```

The `.translate(None, string.punctuation).lower()` does all the magic here and the result is:

```
>>> print f("This test so nice, is like ice! Test... likely;",1)
['ice', 'is', 'like', 'likely', 'nice', 'so', 'test', 'this']
```

Guys, i love one liner function :) But if python beginners are asking here, we should not so much pay attention to our preferences, but rather towards a code that gives a good insight into python and why things behave like they do, so regards to the chosen answer, readable for beginners!